# Uniform continuity in a closed interval

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I want to show that if f:I ⟹ ℝ is uniform continuous, and the interval I is bounded, then f is bounded. But I am not sure how to prove that. I know that if the interval I is bounded, the function will take on all values between f(a) and f(b) in the closed interval I = [a,b], such that a < x < b.  But I am not sure where to go from here.

Comment: A closed interval is compact so is bounded. Since you only have a bounded interval, e.g. $(0,1)$, you must use uniform continuity.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the argument is similar to the soundness theorem. But to make use of the uniform continuous part, the convergent sequence should be replaced by Cauchy. That is:

Assume $f$ is unbounded in $I$, then you can pick a sequence $\{x_n\}\in I$ with $|f(x_n)|>n$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Bolzano-Weiestrass Theorem will give a convergent subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}$, which is Cauchy in $\mathbb{R}$. So $\{f(x_{n_k})\}$ is also Cauchy, so it is convergent and thus bounded. This contradicts to unboundness of $f$ over $I$.